# Missing origin file on UI crash stacktrace

Tags: flutter

I'm facing an issue related with UI crashes on my Flutter application related with the Stacktrace. I used the following broken code to reproduce the issue:

```dart
ListView.separated(
              // shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: context.symmetricInsets(vertical: Spacing.space16),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('title', style: theme.textTheme.suisse15Regular),
                      Text('subtitle', style: theme.textTheme.suisse15Regula),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const UIDivider(),
              itemCount: 10,
            ),
```

This code crash because the `ListView` is inside a `Column`. The problem is, when the error is output on the console (and the same behavior happens on Crashlytics), the Stacktrace doesn't include the origin of the issue:

```
#0      debugCheckHasBoundedAxis.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/debug.dart:328:13)
#1      debugCheckHasBoundedAxis (package:flutter/src/rendering/debug.dart:387:4)
#2      RenderViewport.computeDryLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1372:12)
#3      RenderBox.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2397:12)
#4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2374:9)
#5      RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#6      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#7      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#8      RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#9      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#11     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#12     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#13     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#14     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#15     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#17     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#18     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#19     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#20     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#21     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#23     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#24     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:52:11)
#25     RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:808:43)
#26     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:903:32)
#27     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#28     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#29     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:238:12)
#30     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#31     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#32     _RenderSingleChildViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart:491:14)
#33     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#34     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#35     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#36     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#37     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#38     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#39     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#40     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#41     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#42     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#43     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#44     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#45     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#46     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#47     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#48     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#49     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#50     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#52     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#53     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:52:11)
#54     RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:868:45)
#55     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:903:32)
#56     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#57     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#58     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:52:11)
#59     RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:868:45)
#60     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:903:32)
#61     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#62     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#63     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:238:12)
#64     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#65     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#66     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#67     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#68     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#69     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#70     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1449:11)
#71     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#72     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#73     RenderSliverFillRemainingWithScrollable.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_fill.dart:89:14)
#74     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#75     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:139:12)
#76     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:361:11)
#77     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#78     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:534:13)
#79     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1511:12)
#80     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1420:20)
#81     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#82     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#83     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#84     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#85     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#86     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#87     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#88     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#89     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#90     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#91     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#92     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#93     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#94     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#95     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#96     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#97     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#98     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#99     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#100    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#101    ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:52:11)
#102    RenderStack._computeSize (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:580:43)
#103    RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:607:12)
#104    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#105    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#106    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#107    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#108    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#109    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#110    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#111    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#112    RenderStack.layoutPositionedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:511:11)
#113    RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:620:30)
#114    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#115    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#116    RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:238:12)
#117    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#118    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#119    ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:52:11)
#120    RenderStack._computeSize (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:580:43)
#121    RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:607:12)
#122    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#123    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#124    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#125    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#126    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#127    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#128    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#129    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#130    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#131    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#132    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#133    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#134    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#135    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#136    ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:52:11)
#137    RenderStack._computeSize (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:580:43)
#138    RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:607:12)
#139    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#140    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#141    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#142    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#143    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#144    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#145    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#146    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#147    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#148    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#149    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#150    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#151    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#152    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#153    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#154    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#155    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#156    RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3749:14)
#157    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#158    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#159    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#160    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#161    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#162    _RenderTheaterMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:832:15)
#163    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2234:7)
#164    PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1016:18)
#165    RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:492:19)
#166    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:905:13)
#167    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:358:5)
#168    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1284:15)
#169    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1214:9)
#170    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1072:5)
#171    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:142:13)
#172    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:359:5)
#173    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:112:31)
```

So for crashes happening in production, I have no clue from what page they're being thrown. Any suggestions to fix this stacktrace and include the origin of the issue on it? I tried to use https://pub.dev/packages/stack_trace to better format the trace but no positive results.

OBS: The errors are being catch in the `main.dart` of the app as follows:

```dart
final logger = LoggerGateway();

PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stackTrace) {
    logger.logError(error, stackTrace);
    return true;
  };

  runApp(AppRoot());

  FlutterError.onError =
      (details) => Zone.current.handleUncaughtError(details.exception, details.stack ?? StackTrace.current);
```

Comment: Are you looking on how to solve the problem, or how to include the error in a stacktrace?

Comment: Both. I need to know in which screen the UI errors was thrown to figure out what happened

Comment: You can't have a `ListView` within a `Column`. If you want to do that, you need to wrap the `ListView` with an `Expanded` widget

Comment: Yes, I understand why the issue is happening. The problem is that I have no idea where it's happening. The question is how to make the error stacktrace expose the exact screen the issue is happening instead searching for all possible ListView widgets inside Columns

Comment: This more about the Stacktrace than the error it's exposing. I know how to fix it, I just don't know where it's happening

Answer (score 1):

I implemented FlutterError class inside main method, and It shows something like the output I attached below the code. Is that what you want?

```dart
FlutterError.onError =  (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
    debugPrint('FlutterErrorDetails: $details');
};
```

Output in the console:

```
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ Test STACK_TRACE: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞══════════════════════<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ The following assertion was thrown during performResize():<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ container. In this case, a vertical viewport was given an<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ situation typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ inside another scrollable widget.<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ no need to use a viewport because there will always be enough<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ Column or Wrap instead. Otherwise, consider using a<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ CustomScrollView to concatenate arbitrary slivers into a single<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ scrollable.<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ <…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ The relevant error-causing widget was:<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔   ListView<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔   ListView:file:///Users/macbook/Documents/SVN/IAMS_Mobile/development_v1.0.0/sowat_dev/lib/modules/maps/screens/m_view_map_screen.dart:310:18<…>
m_view_map_screen.dart:310
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ <…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ #0      RenderViewport.computeDryLayout.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1427:15)<…>
viewport.dart:1427
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ #1      RenderViewport.computeDryLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1488:6)<…>
viewport.dart:1488
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ #2      RenderBox.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2441:12)<…>
box.dart:2441
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ ⛔ #3      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2168:9)<…>
object.dart:2168
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just implemented this and sending the app for review in the next days. If the crash reports start to show the stacktrace, I'll mark this as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try it

```
FlutterError.onError =  (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
    debugPrint('${Get.currentRoute}: $details');
};
```